# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'" in Python

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

I am still stuck after trying all the answers I have found here. Please suggest how to go about it. print soup is running but attribute error is not going.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/New-York--NY--United-States/all?checkin=2017-11-05&checkout=2017-11-10&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=fE7Oc2kI'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = r'C:\Users\Vaibhav\Downloads\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows-bin-phantomjs.exe')

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html5lib")

#print soup

div1 = soup.find('div', class_ = 'cardGrid_o1rkka')

for div2 in div1.find_all('div', class_ = 'container_j4k9t6-o_O-column-sm-1_zdxht7-o_O-column-md-2_3504zm-o_O-column-lg-2_14svpwf-o_O-column-xl-3_19vi8ax'):

    title_span = div2.find('span', class_ = 'text_5mbkop-o_O-size_small_1gg2mc-o_O-weight_bold_153t78d-o_O-inline_g86r3e')
    print title_span.text

    price_span = div2.find('span', class_ = 'accessible_1m8bb6v')
    print price_span.text

    if 'reviews' in div2.text:
        review_span = div2.find_all('span')[len(div2.find_all('span')) - 1]
        print review_span.text
driver.quit()
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vaibhav\Desktop\Python Course\Airbnbscrap\airbnbpart1.py", line 31, in <module>
    for div2 in div1.find_all('div', class_ = 'container_j4k9t6-o_O-column-sm-1_zdxht7-o_O-column-md-2_3504zm-o_O-column-lg-2_14svpwf-o_O-column-xl-3_19vi8ax'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

[Editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb5E0.png).

Comment: `div1` is returning `None`. You should make `div1` contain something if you want to use `find` or its similars.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar how to make div1 something? 
 PLease check below

Comment: @halfer check the code and error below

Comment: @VGhildiyal, are you sure you know what are you saying? It's an explanation with no specific target. Could you please narrow down what data you wanna get from that page?